# Naming style for Interfaces

Tags: c#, naming

Looking at the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface i am wondering if the style for naming interfaces should also allow the "IDoThis"-style. Most interfaces seem to be named in the "I am" style, i.e. "IEqualityComparer" or "IPersistable".

Are there more examples of the first naming-variant in the .NET base libs?

And are there updates to the C# naming guidelines I missed, as the MSDN still states:

> "Name interfaces with nouns or noun phrases, or adjectives that
>   describe behavior"

The background is a clash of naming conventions in the current project where I am arguing that "IDoThis"-interfaces should be renamed to fall in line with common naming conventions of the framework.

Comment: We hit this naming quirk when creating interfaces that describe what items can provide, or what items "have". We ran with it as it lets us leak a little LOLcode into the mix: IHasStatistics, etc. :-)

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanging` are probably exceptions rather than a rule. Note how they don't make a lot of sense anyway, as you do not notify a changed or a changing property, but you notify someone or something *about* said property, or *when* a property has changed/is changing.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: :) I would go for "IStatistic" or "IStatisticProvider" in that example. But the LOLCode definitely makes for funnier names. Now where can I add an interface which defines whether or not another class can have a bucket...

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Yes they do feel like exceptions to me too, but it seems strange to see naming conventions being broken in the .NET base libs. I would assume that at least there the naming police keeps a good watch. So maybe this kind of style is allowed internally at MS.

Comment: @GaussZ I'm waiting for the day when one of our classes is responsible for distributing cheese burgers... but to your point, yes most of the time our naming is sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I think your example is an exception, as there isn't a concise noun, noun phrase or adjective that's as expressive (`IPropertyChangingNotifier` is a mouthful)

Another exception from the framework is `INormalizeForIsolatedStorage` (better than `INormalizeableForIsolatedStorage`).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the additional example. I wonder how many can be found in the framework. If only there were a simple grammatical analyse one could run over the list of interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I've never felt the need to use verb or verb-noun suffixes for interface names. Most of the time, a noun or adjective suffices as the guideline describes.

Given that an interface is typically a collection of methods and properties, the use of a IVerb or IVerbNoun type name would be non-sensical most of the time.

Do you have any examples of IVerb or IVerbNoun interface names that you're using at the moment?

Comment: I am not using them, as I stick to the "I am" style. But other team members use a lot of "IProvideUsers", "ISaveUsers" or "ICompile" e.g..

Comment: Perhaps the interface name is being driven by the concretion which in turn may be poorly named...

Comment: It seems to be a personal preference for interfaces that can be spoken  as a sentence so the class header can be read as: "class Driver: I drive cars".

Comment: Interesting. Reminds me of an old C contractor we had who always declared a constant called chicken just so his first line could be : chicken char main()